# Upload files using the FTP Ant Task with a timestamp

Tags: ant, ftp

I have the following code working. I've done some searching and can't find anything on how to associate a time stamp for when each file is uploaded. This would be helpful since I can get an idea on when a file fails during the upload process.

```
<ftp password="${password}" server="${server}" userid="${userid}"    passive="true" remotedir="${remoteDir}">
        <fileset dir="${localDir}">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
```

Basically, instead of this being produced in the log:

```
[ftp] File /DirectorytoUploadto/File.xml copied to server
```

I want to have something along the lines of:

```
[ftp] File /DirectorytoUploadto/File.xml copied to server at 2013-10-01 12:19:09
```

Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To get a timestamp for each logged message, use the [Log4J Listener](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html#Log4jListener).